# npm does not install local dependencies to .bin

Tags: npm, node-modules

I am using a local dependency in npm, called with the [*file:* syntax](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths). However, the binaries from these modules are not put into the *.bin* directory within the *node_module* directory of my module. I would expect npm to behave the same as packages downloaded from the registry. My folder structure looks like this:

```
COMMON
-- node_modules
   -- .bin
      module_a
      module_b
my_package
-- module_foo
   module_bar
   symlink to COMMON
```

Running `npm bin` gives ".\node_modules.bin" and I've tried adding "bin" and "directories.bin" to my [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin), but it doesn't seem to do what I need. Is there a way to make npm bring in the *.bin* files from local dependencies or add an additional folder to the path where npm has *node_modules.bin*?

I am on Windows 10, npm 5.4.2, and node 6.11.3

Thank you!

Comment: Got a solution?